# Maximum Principle for nonlinear elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, maximum-principle

I've followed a course about elliptic equations. I've studied the maximum principle for linear elliptic pde's in its various forms. I was wondering if I can use them to deduce something useful for classical (sub/super)solutions of nonlinear elliptic equations(in the sense that the linearization is elliptic).
The particular problem in which I've come across and inspired my question is this one: if $u$ is a classical subsolution to Monge-Ampere equation with zero boundary data:
$$ \begin{cases}
      \det(D^2u)\geq 0 & \text{in }\Omega\\
      u=0  & \text{on }\partial\Omega 
    \end{cases}
$$
what can I say about the sign of $u$ in $\Omega$?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much in general. Consider $n=4$ and

$$u(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2.$$

Then $\text{det}(\nabla^2 u)=1$ but $u$ does not have a sign on, say, the unit ball.

The convex Monge-Ampere equation satisfies a comparison principle. That is, when you have convex sub- and supersolutions $u$ and $v$, and $u\leq v$ on $\partial \Omega$, then $u\leq v$ on $\Omega$. This actually holds in the weaker viscosity sense (see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207212). The proof follows a maximum principle argument for nonlinear PDEs.

It's crucially important that the solutions are convex though. In your case, if $u$ is convex, then its maximum occurs on the boundary and so $u\leq 0$ on $\Omega$ (without using Monge-Ampere).